# In fiddler core's new version (4.6.3.50306) some preferences are missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, fiddler, fiddlercore, fiddler-dev

In fiddler core's new versions (4.6.3.50306) i can't able to get all the preferences (especially "**fiddler.certmaker.bc.cert**" & "**fiddler.certmaker.bc.key**") but in the old version (i.e. 4.5.1) its working fine.

```
FiddlerApplication.Prefs.GetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.cert", null));
FiddlerApplication.Prefs.GetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.key", null));
```

Even in the fiddler application's preference list these two preferences are missing

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why new version was not giving me the values for those two preferences (**fiddler.certmaker.bc.cert & fiddler.certmaker.bc.key**), may be because it was using "**CertEnroll engine**", and the old version was using "**BCCertMaker.BCCertMaker from CertMaker.dll**"

But instead of using

```
FiddlerApplication.Prefs.GetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.cert", null));
FiddlerApplication.Prefs.GetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.key", null));
```

I used

```
CertMaker.GetRootCertificate().GetPublicKeyString());
CertMaker.GetRootCertificate().GetRawCertDataString();
```

And now it is working fine and giving me the key string and cert string.